# Iterating through a string, to place each element into its own list element

Tags: python, string, list, loops

In Python, I'm trying to iterate through a string using a for loop, to produce a list that splits out each individual element of the original string, into a new list that has each element in its own index spot:

If i have the string 'HAHAHA':

```py
    word = 'HAHAHA'
    word_check = []

    for i in word:
         word_check.append(i)
```

Right now, I'm getting ['HAHAHA'], but i'm trying to return: ['H','A', 'H', 'A', 'H', 'A'].  Can someone help me out?  I've searched around, and i see some variations, but not the exact output i'm looking for.  Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I just tried your sample code and it returned ['H', 'A', 'H', 'A', 'H', 'A'].

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult actually, just **cast it as a list**.

```py
st = 'HAHAHA'

print(list(st))
['H', 'A', 'H', 'A', 'H', 'A']
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I also just realized, I need another variation...what would I do, to split a list that contains a string, into those individual elements?  so in this case:

st = ['HAHAHA']

and i'm still trying to get to: ['H','A','H','A','H','A','H','A']

I appreciate the help, thanks again!

Comment: nevermind, i got it!  it'd just be: list(word[0])
thanks again for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on what Djib2011 said this should be exactly what you want

`word = 'HAHAHA'
 word_check = list(word)`